# Using Mean value theorem to prove the inequality $1.995<129^{1/7}<2.005$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How can I prove the following inequality using mean value theorem?
$$1.997<129^{1/7}<2.003$$

#### Progress

Comment: Please share with us what you have thought regarding this problem.

Comment: Suggestion: $f(x) = x^{1/7}$. Observe that $f(128)=2$.

Comment: may i ask how to choose an interval for mvt?

Comment: based on @Rafflesiaarnoldii hint you can choose the interval as $[128, 129]$ and apply MVT

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have already applied MVT on the interval, may i ask how to get to the inequalities that i need?thank you

Comment: @user3437854: we have $f(129)=f(128) +f'(c) = 2+ f'(c)$. Now $f'(c)=(1/7)c^{-6/7}$ where $128<c<129$.  Try to show that $f'(c) <3/1000$. You need to use the fact that $c^{1/7}>2$. The first part $1.997 <f(129)$ is obvious as $f(129)>2$.

Comment: really thank you so much!! i got it already! @paramanand singh  thanks!!anyway can up my reputation?so that I can vote for others

Comment: @rafflesia arnoldii thx too!

Comment: One has $129^{1/7}>128^{1/7}=2$ without any theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We shall use the MVT in the following form: If $f$ is differentiable on the interval $[0,x]$  then there is a $\xi\in\ ]0,x[\ $ with
$$f(x)=f(0)+x\>f'(\xi)\ .\tag{1}$$
Apply this to the function
$$f(x):=(1+x)^{1/7}\qquad(x\geq0)$$
and obtain
$$f(x)=1+x\cdot {1\over 7}(1+\xi)^{-6/7}\leq1+{x\over7}\ .$$
It follows that
$$129^{1/7}=2\left(1+{1\over 128}\right)^{1/7}\leq2\left(1+{1\over 7\cdot 128}\right)<2.002233\ .$$
On the other hand, from $129\left(1-{1\over129}\right)=128$ we get
$$129^{1/7}=2\left(1-{1\over 129}\right)^{-1/7}\ .\tag{2}$$
This time we apply $(1)$ to the function
$$f(x):=(1-x)^{-1/7}\qquad(0\leq x<1)$$
and obtain
$$f(x)=1+x\cdot{1\over7}(1-\xi)^{-8/7}\geq1+{x\over7}\ .$$
From $(2)$ it then follows that
$$129^{1/7}\geq 2\left(1+{1\over 7\cdot 129}\right)>2.002214\ .$$
The true value is $2.002224705\ldots\ .$

Comment: THanks for the suggestions!, might up my reputation so that i can vote for u? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^{1/7}$, and note that $f(128)=2$.  Note also that $f'(x)={1\over7}x^{-6/7}={1\over7f(x)^6}$.  By the Mean Value Theorem,

$${f(129)-f(128)\over129-128}=f'(c)$$

for some $128\lt c\lt 129$.  Thus $129^{1/7}=2+f'(c)$ with $|f'(c)|={1\over7f(c)^6}\lt{1\over7\cdot2^6}={1\over7\cdot64}\lt{3\over1000}$, since $1000\lt21\cdot64$.

Remark:  The inequality can, of course, be strengthened since in fact 
$$0.0011\lt{1\over7\cdot129}\lt{1\over7\cdot129^{6/7}}\lt f'(c)\lt{1\over448}\lt0.0023$$